# Extend display to second laptop

Tags: extended-desktop, multiple-computers

If I have two laptops, can I extend my display from the first one to the second one? Kindly note that I do not have a monitor, and both the laptops are equipped with HDMI out ports.

Is there any way to work this around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Windows 10 Wireless Display

You can't use VGA cables or HDMI cable to connect a desktop to a laptop and use it as a second monitor as the VGA and HDMI ports on laptops are for video out but not for video in. However, you can use Windows 10 wireless displays.

### Like This:

1. On the machine you want to use as a 2nd monitor, go to `Settings > System > Projecting to this PC` then set it up.
2. Now, from your main machine that you are projecting from press <kbd>Windows Key+P</kbd> as if you are projecting to a projector or second display.
3. Now hit "Connect to a Wireless Display".

The downside to this is you can sometimes have a lag, depending on the data speeds you have, but it's a good solution nevertheless.

[Further reading](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-laptop-like-external-monitor/)

> If you don’t have another monitor, but do have a separate laptop,
>   you’re in good hands. It is extremely easy to create your own
>   multi-monitor setup without cables, using your home network, with a
>   host of tools to help you get the job done. Let’s take a look!

Comment: If you found this helpful, please feel free to upvote and/or mark as an answer. Thanks Abhinav :)